# Ubuntu 14.04 very slow even with video card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, video

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my computer that already had windows installed system.
The graphical windows is very peforming due to the video card that I have installed.
But the ubuntu was not so well. Anything related to graphic is very slow in ubuntu.
There's something I can do to improve this peforming being that I have a video card my computer?
Information follows the video card:

```
~$ lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] [10de:0a65] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Thanks advance..

**Edit**
I followed all steps in this tutorial:
http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/

 But when I run: 
`lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12` 
at the end I have: 
`Kernel driver in use: nouveau`

 And keep slow.

Comment: You're still using nouveau. Did you reboot after selecting the proprietary driver from Additional Drivers tab as described in the tutorial? You have to reboot before the changes take effect.

Comment: Yes. I did. But nothing yet..

Answer (score 2):

Go to system-settings, click on "Software & Updates", and go to the "Aditional Drivers" tab.

From there, you can select the "tested" proprietary nvidia driver.

Furthermore, there's all kinds of stuff you can do to get support for your graphics card. Alot of times, when you run a program, you are not using "hardware acceleration" and so your graphics card is not used. This is such a broad area I would not be able to be more specific than to say these few suggestions:

- Install synaptic and use synaptic to search for and install all the "opengl" packages for your card that are available (always pay attention to what may subsequently be *uninstalled* so you don't make a mistake when doing this).
- Enable hardware acceleration in the settings for every application you use that may gain from using the graphics card like vlc for example.
- If you are using chromium or google-chrome, go to the url "chrome:flags" and click on the first option to "Override software rendering list" and then restart chrome. To check your GPU status in chrome go to the url "chrome:gpu".

Finally, run these commands to allow hardware acceleration when using firefox adobe flashplayer:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/adobe
echo "EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=1" | sudo tee /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
echo "OverrideGPUValidation=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
```

Comment: If you follow all the steps above will realize that I've done much of what you're saying. Only attempt with synaptics did not understand correctly.